# How to refresh calculation instantaneously in excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a problem in refreshing the cell's calculation.

In other words, I have many columns where i have a formula or macro in each one of them.

But the problem is that i should absolutely activate the option " automatic calculation" in the excel options or i should save then the new results appear.

Now, I would insert something in the macro that can refresh me the results instantaneously.

Thanks

Comment: Use `Call Application.Calculate`

Answer (score 8):

To force all formulas to update, including custom vba formulas, execute the following in VBA:

```
Application.CalculateFullRebuild
```

This can also be executed from the VBA immediate window.

More documentation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.calculatefullrebuild

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! The others did not work for me!

Answer (score 3):

You could simply press :

`F9` to calculate the whole active workbook

`Shift + F9` to calculate the active sheet

---

Anyway, here are the different options with `.Calculate` :

```
Sub Souma()

'Use this to calculate all the open workbooks
Application.Calculate

'Use this to calculate the whole sheet, called "Sheet1"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Calculate


'Use this to calculate the cell A1 on the sheet called "Sheet1"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Calculate
'Use this to calculate the range A1 to D10 on the sheet called "Sheet1"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D10").Calculate
'Use this to calculate the column A on the sheet called "Sheet1"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(1).Calculate
'Use this to calculate the row 1 on the sheet called "Sheet1"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(1).Calculate

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried ur solution but it still doesn't work.. the problem is that i have linked formulas in each column ..when i change one of them ..all cells should refresh it result without clicking anywhere

Comment: You mean that you are already in `Automatic calculation` mode? And that **F9** didn't refresh the values? What about the code? Because if it didn't update with code nor keyboard, you might have another issue there.

Comment: Without 'Automatic CALCULATION' neither F9.. because this workbook will be used by other collaborators..and not everyone know how to activate "automatic calculation" ..this is why i wanna something in the code that can refresh the results automatically

Comment: Do you think that i should add a button that refresh the results ?

Answer (score 2):

Copy and paste the code below to your VBA project:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

This code should automatically run after you open the Excel file, enabling automatic calculation in *all* opened files.