# how to refresh an excel file from within R?

Tags: r, excel

I have some excel file with simple formulas like `=SUM(A1:A3)`.

I need to import the file into `R`, but before that I need to refresh the formulas. Is there a way to refresh the file from within `R`? There are good packages for importing the data in a R dataframe (eg. the R `xslx` package) but I need to refresh my formulas first.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: why the downvote? this is a legit question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this with RDCOMClient:

```
library(RDCOMClient)
ex = COMCreate("Excel.Application")
book = ex$Workbooks()$Open("my_file.xlsx")
book$Worksheets("Sheet1")$Calculate() # if you have many sheets you could loop through them or use apply functions based on their actual names
book$Save()
book$Close()
```

Here's another thread on the [underlying VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31959317/how-to-refresh-calculation-instantaneously-in-excel)

Comment: For me `$Calculate()` did not work. But `book$RefreshAll()` did the trick,