# "Error: OutOfMemoryError (Java): Java heap space" when loading a small file with XLConnect

Tags: java, r, jvm, rstudio, xlconnect

First of all I must say that I have long looked for a solution to my problem and that starting this thread is a desperate attempt. All the information (and their respective solutions) relate to memory leaks when running several iterations of a code or when dealing with heavy files (>500Mb). But that's not my case.

My code -before the error is triggered- looks like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(XLConnect)
library(tibble)
library(rJava)

path <- "file_path/file_name.xlsx"

wb <- loadWorkbook(path)
```

This triggers the following message:

> Error: OutOfMemoryError (Java): Java heap space

The size of *file* is only 7Mb. If I try uploading a smaller file (500Kb) I get no error. I already tried setting a higher value for Java memory with `options(java.parameters = "-Xmx8g")` but it didn't solve the problem.

Garbage Collector looks like this:

> ```
>       used (Mb) gc trigger  (Mb) max used  (Mb)
> ```
>
> Ncells 1157125 61.8    2240345 119.7  2240345 119.7
>
> Vcells 1793273 13.7    8388608  64.0  2904659  22.2

Does anyone have an idea of what could be causing this? My enviroment is completelly clean and I continously re-start my Rstudio session. The file is simply an .xlsx document that I need to load in order to fill columns with data from a dataframe.

Comment: Not a reply, but the `readxl` package might be an alternative, plus it's Java-free. There's also `openxlsx` if you need to do more than reading files.

Comment: I normally use `openxlsx`, but for this project I encountered an issue that could not be overcome, and so I need to use `XLConnect` (or, alternatively, `xlsx`; both Java-based). See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77556047/saving-and-opening-an-excel-file-with-openxlsx-data-is-missing?noredirect=1#comment136726401_77556047

Answer (score 0):

It is important to set Java options **before** the JVM is initialized and as such **before** any Java-related package is loaded. So you should have:

```
options(java.parameters = "-Xmx8g")

library(XLConnect)
path <- "file_path/file_name.xlsx"
wb <- loadWorkbook(path)
```

Comment: Thank you Martin, that's a good point. I was updating JVM memory from the console and somehow didn't realize about this. Now I'm getting an `ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation` error, but that's another story. I'd say your answer solved my problem.